# ImportError: No module named pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

I am trying to use the pandas data reader library.
I initially tried `import pandas.io.data` but this threw up an import error, stating I should be using

> from pandas_datareader import data, wb

instead. Upon trying this I was greeted with

> ImportError: No module named pandas_datareader

I have had a look around and have tried...

- "pip install pandas_datareader"
- "pip install python_datareader"
- "pip install pandas-datareader"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this command `pip install pandas-datareader` and for more info documentation is [here](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)